# Error using find command to find, compress and delete files

Tags: linux, shell, find

I need to find files, compress and delete them.

Example: In the current directory, I have files "log.0", "log.1" and "log.2". If I run:

```
find . -type f -exec tar -zcvf "logs.tar.gz" "{}" \;
```

and decompress the file `logs.tar.gz`, I will get only the file `log.0`.

How can I compress all files found in `find` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
tar -zcvf logs.tar.gz --null --files-from - --remove-files
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Why the use of parameters --null and --files-from?

Comment: `find -print0` prints the file names zero-terminated to stdout.  `tar --files-from -` reads the files to be compressed from stdin, while `--null` tells that the file names are zero-terminated. The zero-termination is a safety feature to properly handle the file names with spaces/etc.